# Как реализовать клиент-серверное взаимодействие на java?

Tags: java, android

В качестве клиента выступает приложение на Android, приложение - чат. Связал его с Firebase RealtimeDatabase и Authentication, но появилось желание расширить свою идею до собственного сервера, чтобы на нем обрабатывалась регистрация, вход пользователей, хранение данных. Подскажите что почитать из литературы, полезные ссылки, статьи будут очень кстати. Слышал про Spring, что в нём есть все нужное, но там столько всего, что не знаю в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: у спринга кучу всего из под коробки. плюс di (покруче даггера2). из литературы спринг в действии на англ языке. видеоуроки

Comment: @Санаев хотел бы я посмотреть на андроид проект, у которого spring DI

Comment: @keekkenen с чем могут возникнуть проблемы?

Comment: я не в курсе, если ли реализация spring DI для андроида.. DI daggerа будет быстрее, поскольку spring построен на рефлексии

Comment: @keekkenen я имею в виду что спринговский ди получше ди даггер2

Comment: @keekkenen зато при этом классов меньше и путаницы . тестирование легче

Answer (score 2):

Собственно, вы все правильно слышали. Spring довольно мудреная штука для начинающего, но разобраться реально, материалов на русском тьма. Кучи "упростителей", например в Idea есть плагин выполняющий существенную часть работ по первичной настройке проекта(правда вроде только в платой версии, но может триал поможет, для начала). Spring мало того, что точно полностью покроет ваши потребности, еще и даст вам крайне полезный опыт, штука в корпоративной разработке весьма популярная.

Без него вполне реально все равно написать свой сервер. Если схема взаимодействия не особо мудреная - можно просто через сокеты слать сообщения. Тоже полезный опыт, но если захочется расширять функционал, придется туговато. По крайней мере мне не захотелось бы возиться с сокетами, когда в них нет необходимости :)

В общем, если вы собираетесь кормится за счет разработки на Java - однозначно осваивайте Spring. Если вы балуетесь для души - останьтесь на firebase или сделайте сервер с которым будете общаться через сокеты

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, теперь буду точно заинтересован в изучении Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще в ответах выше - вода(пожелания здоровья и т.д и т.п). Если ходите использовать Spring, используйте Spring boot, а конкретнее Spring Websoсket для чата, а для андроид клиента okhttp3 WebSocketListener, в данном случае написано на котлин:

```
    private val listener = object : WebSocketListener() {

    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        runOnUiThread {
            open.text = "Send"
        }
        webSocket.send("What's up ?")
    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket?, text: String?) {
        runOnUiThread {
            text_1.text = text_1.text.toString() + "\n" + text
        }
    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket?, bytes: ByteString) {

    }

    override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String?) {
        runOnUiThread {
            text_1.text = "Closed"
            open.text = "Open"
        }
        webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null)
        ws = null
    }

}

    private lateinit var client: OkHttpClient

    var ws: WebSocket? = null

        client = OkHttpClient()

        if (ws != null) {
            ws!!.send(input.text.toString())
        } else {
            try {
                val request = Request.Builder()
                    .header("Authorization", "bearer b4e3210d-4279-415f-8071-701b1c6198f4")
                    .url("ws://192.168.0.78:8080/ws/first")
                    .build()
                ws = client
                    .newBuilder()
                    .build()
                    .newWebSocket(request, listener)

                client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

На сервере:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
class WebsocketConfig : WebSocketConfigurer {

@Autowired
lateinit var first: FirstWebsocketHandler


override fun registerWebSocketHandlers(registry: WebSocketHandlerRegistry) {
    registry.addHandler(first, "/ws/first")
}}

@Configuration
class WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig : 
AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer() {

override fun configureInbound(messages: MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry) 
{
    messages.anyMessage().fullyAuthenticated()
}

override fun sameOriginDisabled(): Boolean {
    return true
}}

@Component
class FirstWebsocketHandler : TextWebSocketHandler() {

@Autowired
lateinit var employeeService: EmployeeService


val clients: MutableMap<Employee, WebSocketSession> = mutableMapOf()


override fun handleTextMessage(session: WebSocketSession, message: TextMessage) {
    session.sendMessage(message)

}

override fun afterConnectionEstablished(session: WebSocketSession) {
    try {
        val user = (session.principal as OAuth2Authentication).userAuthentication.principal as User
        val employee = employeeService.getEmployeeByUser(user)!!
        clients[employee] = session
        session.sendMessage(TextMessage("Hello " + employee.firstname))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        session.close(CloseStatus.SERVER_ERROR)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

override fun afterConnectionClosed(session: WebSocketSession, status: CloseStatus) {

}}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, начну разбираться.